# How to get the integrity value for a jquery version for script

Tags: jquery

I have this code from somewhere

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But if I want to use  `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` in https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

how to get the corresponding integrity value for `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`?

Comment: https://www.srihash.org/

Answer (score 47):

Use https://www.srihash.org/ for generate link

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
```

generated as

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This is great when you want to keep the same links in your files. Just generate the link with the integrity code for each one.

Answer (score 9):

Is this something that you are looking for?

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I found this from here -

[jQuery Core – All Versions](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/)

Comment: Yes but where did you find the integrity value ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe someone is also looking for a way without sending your files to a third-party website but just calculate the integrity value locally.

As the suggested site [srihash.org](https://www.srihash.org) describes, it's definately possible with following command (in bash):

```sh
openssl dgst -sha384 -binary jquery-3.3.1.min.js | openssl base64 -A
```

If you would rather like using other algorythms you can do so by specifying them instead of `-sha384` e.g. `-sha512`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer which points to the jQuery site is correct, but incomplete.  It is true that you can find the information by going to https://releases.jquery.com/jquery, but it's not actually visible ON that page.

There's a missing piece of information which is vitally important:

## jQuery.com displays misleading info in the status bar

This hides the fact that you must click the link to get the integrity information.  Despite seeing what looks like a JavaScript file in the status bar, clicking the link actually opens up a dialog box that shows the entire `<script>` tag—including the integrity information—that you will need to use.

I have no idea why they would do this, but that is why it is so hard to find the integrity info, and probably the entire reason this question even exists.